# Google Developer Console for Identity Toolkit is unavailable

Tags: google-app-engine, console

Google's Identity Toolkit developer's console requires use of the "original console" when managing the API. I was using it with no issues for the past few days but starting yesterday it became unavailable.

Clicking on the "original console" link now brings up a mostly blank screen (only the general menu headers remain).  If I go into the original console to manage other aspects and then click on "Identity Toolkit" then a yellow "Loading..." box appears but the screen doesn't change and the API console is not loaded.

If I go into another project I own I am able to get to the screen with no problem.

Has anyone else seen this or know of a work-around or solution?

Comment: Have you tried the following: 1) clearing cookies, 2) access from an incognito window and 3) from a different browser

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried all those things as well as a few more. I answered the question myself in case anyone else runs into the issue. Turns out to be a bug in the Google console.

Answer (score 0):

I spent the past few days with Google Support - it's a bug in the console. They entered my configuration information for me.

They either fixed the bug or the act of entering the information was a sufficient work-around as I now have access to the console.